# javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress RFC 822 validation

Tags: java, email-validation, jakarta-mail, email-address

I would assume that the following would throw but it doesn't.

```
new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress( "a@b......." ).validate
```

My javax.mail version is 1.4. (and java version 8 if it matters). Is this a valid email address according to RFC822 which validate() purports to conform to? http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate says that the above is not a valid RFC822 email address.

Comment: https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.java?rev=557 Line 1268 looks like it tests for this possibility and throws an exception if it finds it.  So you're right, it shouldn't be valid.   Just a silly question, does it matter if you use validate() instead of validate?  Or could this be a Unicode vs. ASCII issue?

Comment: I am using this in Scala, hence wrote `validate` without the `()`. Its the same thing though. I think you mean 1286 for the line, and yes it does look like that is the case. Although looking at the code, I am no longer confident of my usage of this library, it looks very badly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#validate--):

> The current implementation checks many, but not all, syntax rules.

If you can, upgrade your JavaMail version.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Session.getInstance(new Properties()).setDebug(true);
    new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress("a@b......." ).validate();
}
```

Outputs:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.4
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains dot-dot in string ``a@b.......''
     at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1282)
     at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1099)
     at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:638)
     at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:111)
```